# How to enable "Make AI polygon" option for polygon labeling in CVAT?

Tags: image-processing, object-detection, image-segmentation, labeling, cvat

I'm using CVAT for labeling my large dataset but I have a problem. I watched a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9HszWP_qsRQ) on Youtube about semi-automatic segmentation in which there was an option "Make AI Polygon", but I don't have it in my polygon section and don't know how to enable it in my CVAT.
Here is how my CVAT looks like:

[image]

How can I enable "Make AI Polygon" option?